# Using points in polygons tool with QGIS and CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am working with 2 layers.

1 shows a polygon of a district and is in CRS EPSG 4326 and another layer (address layer) is in CRS EPSG 3082.

I right click the address layer and "save as" and specify the same crs as the district layer (epsg 4326).

When performing the "points in polygon function" shouldnt the result be a layer that when I open the attributes table it should show the number of addresses in the "pnt cnt" field?

Is there something I am missing about setting the CRS for all layers to be the same in order to perform Geoprocessing?

Is there another issue that I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour].  Here you are making a series of statements but have not asked the single question that would enable focussed Q&A.  To me it looks like you want to ["participate in a discussion about ______”](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) which makes this off-topic for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you seem to be wanting to participate in a discussion rather than asking a single focussed question.

Comment: Hello PolyGeo, that is fine. Could you please direct me as to where I may post this discussion question?

Comment: I'm sorry, i've read the "participate in discussion " link. Thank you

Comment: On GIS Stack Exchange your only option would be our [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) but you need to accumulate a reputation of 20 first in order to participate there.

Comment: You've edited your question but have not let us know whether you are describing something that you have done in QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop. I have assumed it is the former and have removed your [tag:arcmap] tag.

Comment: Did you save under a different name, and remove the original file from the canvas? Can you add the CRS and extent of the two layers, as reported by rightclick, metadata tab, to your question?